# Trying to add to an arraylist on a different activity each time a button is pressed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So just to practice I've created a Pythagorean theorem calculator app. I want each answer that I obtain to be stored in another activity(a "history" page). I'm trying to use intents to send/receive the arraylist and items. I get the most recent one, but it is overwritten after each press of the button.

```html
package com.example.hypnotenusecalculatorrebuild;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    //ToDo history button is broken. doesn't display listview when pressed.
    public void toHistory(View view) {

//        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HistoryActivity.class);
//
//        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void findHypno(View view) {

        Log.i("Info", "button pressed");

        EditText editTextNumberA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNumberA);
        EditText editTextNumberB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNumberB);
        TextView textViewAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAnswer);

        String message;
        String cSquared;

        if (editTextNumberA.getText().toString().isEmpty() || editTextNumberB.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

            message = "Please enter a number for each dimension";
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            Number numberA = new Number();
            Number numberB = new Number();
            Number numberC = new Number();

            numberA.number = Double.parseDouble(editTextNumberA.getText().toString());
            numberB.number = Double.parseDouble(editTextNumberB.getText().toString());

            numberA.squareNumber();
            numberB.squareNumber();
            numberC.number = numberA.number + numberB.number;
            numberC.squareRoot();

            Log.i("test numberA", String.valueOf(numberA.number));
            Log.i("test numberB", String.valueOf(numberB.number));
            Log.i("test numberC", String.valueOf(numberC.number));

            cSquared = Double.toString(numberC.number);

            textViewAnswer.setText(cSquared);

            ArrayList<String> historyList = new ArrayList<String>();
            historyList.add("test");

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HistoryActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("answer", cSquared);
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("arrayList", historyList);

            startActivity(intent);

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    }
}
```

```html
package com.example.hypnotenusecalculatorrebuild;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.ToDoubleBiFunction;

public class HistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void back(View view) {

        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

        Intent getList = getIntent();
        ArrayList<String> historyList = getList.getStringArrayListExtra("arrayList");
        historyList.add(getList.getStringExtra("answer"));

        ListView listViewHistory = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewHistory);
        ArrayAdapter historyListArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, historyList);
        listViewHistory.setAdapter(historyListArrayAdapter);


        // ToDo - intent isn't working as attended, only saves one item and gets overwritten each time
        //Intent historyIntent = getIntent();

        // get extra needs a name from put extra
//        String testGetIntent = historyIntent.getStringExtra("answer");
//        Log.i("testIntentString", testGetIntent);
//        historyList.add(historyIntent.getStringExtra("answer"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Every time you start a new history activity you give it the last answer u(cSquared string only). After that you will kill the history activity to get back to the MainActivity.

Comment: `ArrayList<String> historyList = new ArrayList<String>();` Do not create a new list every time. Just do it once n onCreate. Then add every time a new answer and give that list to history activity.

Comment: Even then... you will not be ready as getting back from history activity you should not create a new list i think but use the old one. There is a lot to do...

Comment: You can persist data in local database, every Activity will be able to retrieve it from there with consistent API. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a different approach. make a public interface in a separate file named "extensions" or whatever and initialize your arraylist there like so:

```
public interface ext {
    ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

this interface is created when the app runs and lives for as long as the app lives meaning you can always access and manipulate it anywhere in your app without worrying whether the activity is being killed or not. so you can add or remove elements to or from it wherever you want.

Access the array this way:

```
ext.myArray.add("new item")
```